# Datatype in Typescript to store any component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Consider this method in Typescript.

```
public openComponent(component: any, data: ComponentData): void {

    this.modalService.open(component);
}
```

This tries to open any given angular component in a modal. Just want to know if there is a way to get rid of `any` in `component: any` and make it typed?

In short is there a datatype in Typescript to store any component reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [Type](https://angular.io/api/core/Type)

```
public openComponent<T>(component: Type<T>, data: ComponentData): void {
    this.modalService.open(component);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I want to know which of these to is better and should be followed. `any` seems simpler and easy to understand to me.

Comment: Avoid `any` usage, that's a golden rule :)

Answer (score 2):

Kostenko answer is correct, just wanted to give you an alternative, a Component is just a Class, so it can be *typed* like this:

```
/** Interface that can be used to generically type a class. */
export interface ComponentType<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Then, this should also work:

```
public openComponent<T>(component: ComponentType<T>, data: ComponentData): void {
    this.modalService.open(component);
}
```

It can be useful in certain scenarios.